Did Krishna's wives commit Sati when he passed away?
In the article (accessible through JSTOR)
SOCIAL PRESSURES BEHIND THE BHĀRGAVA INTERPOLATION OF THE MAHĀBHĀRATA
S. Bhattacharji
Annals of the Bhandarkar Oriental Research Institute, Vol. 72/73, No. 1/4, Amrtamahotsava (1917-1992) Volume (1991-1992), pp. 469-482 (14 pages)
the author says
Satyabhama, Rukmini and other wives committed Sati.

See my answer here https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/60458/15087

why don't you write an answer citing multiple sources? @CracklingCyclone

As per Mahabharata several wives of Krishna committed sati and several others practiced celibacy.

Rukmini, the princess of Gandhara, Saivya, Haimavati, and queen
Jamvabati ascended the funeral pyre. Satyabhama and other dear wives
of Krishna entered the woods, O king, resolved to set themselves to
the practice of penances. They began to live on fruits and roots and
pass their time in the contemplation of Hari.
[Mahabharata Mausala parva Chapter 7]

